# Automount external storage as user readable and writable in Debian XFCE?

Tags: permissions, automounting, usb-drive

I have Debian Wheezy installed with the latest XFCE desktop environment.
In the XFCE settings, I specified that external media be automounted upon insertion.

However, when I plug in my USB stick, it appears on my desktop, but is not mounted because there is no permission. In fact I have to use sudo to mount, access, read, and write from the USB drive.

I don't want to use the fstab method because you need an entry for each unique device and it is simply very inefficient.

How can I setup my system so that whenever I plug in an external storage device, it will automount and be fully user accessible? It seems a little silly that this functionality does not come "out of the box" and "just work" (or at least easily enabled) in the 21st century... :)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: what Login Manager are you using (slim, gdm, xdm ...)?

Answer (score 3):

make sure that the following packages are installed:

`gvfs` and  `thunar-volman`

and make sure that at your `~/.xinitrc` file, there is aline like `exec ck-launch-session startxfce4` (it normally the last line at that file),

and you make sure that you are member of the `plugdev` group with the `id` command with the regular user, in case you aren't add your user to it with `useradd -G plugdev username`.

if you need more details see [here](http://techpatterns.com/forums/about1952.html).

Answer (score 1):

Could try [usbmount](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/usbmount).  This question is probably [a dupe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24731/automounting-usb-sticks-on-debian/24838#24838).  Please read instructions there.

Comment: Pay attention to `usbmount` and NTFS: https://bugs.debian.org/774149

Answer (score 0):

Afaik you need to add your user to the group `plugdev`.

In console:

```
sudo adduser <yourusername> plugdev
```