# Can Ubuntu 16.04 setup autofs to automount /media/autousb with read and write permissions if am user frank?

Tags: ubuntu, udev, autofs

I spent 6 hours yesterday testing @Ingo Blackman's answer to the 
Unix and Linux Stack Exchange article,

[[Automounting USB sticks on Debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24731/automounting-usb-sticks-on-debian])

When I use a udev rule ACTION=="add" and RUN+="/bin/ln -sf /media/autousb/%k /media/frank/usb/%k" , shown immediately below:

```
# Add symlink /dev/usbdisks/<label> to /dev/sd[a-z][1-9] 
# for automounter support

ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="sd*", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="partition", \
    ENV{ID_BUS}=="usb", \
    SYMLINK+="usbdisks/%k", MODE:="0660", \
    RUN+="/bin/rm /media/usb/%k", \
    RUN+="/bin/ln -sf /media/autousb/%k /media/frank/usb/%k"

# Some FileSystems emit a "change" event when they are unmounted.
# UDEV seems to delete the device symlink in this case :-(
# So we need to re-create it here
ACTION=="change", KERNEL=="sd*", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="partition", \
    ENV{ID_BUS}=="usb", \
    SYMLINK+="usbdisks/%k", MODE:="0660"


# When device is removed, also remove /media/usb/<...>
ACTION=="remove", KERNEL=="sd*", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="partition", \
    ENV{ID_BUS}=="usb", \
    RUN+="/bin/rm /media/frank/usb/%k"
```

the udev or autofs service creates the directory /media/autousb with 755 permission rather than 777 permission so that udev or autofs cannot create regular files or soft links inside /media/autousb.

May I ask how to fix this?

My simplistic hypothesis is that since I am Ubuntu 16.04 user frank belonging 
to the group plugdev along with user root, the above udev add rule should work if I change use /media/autousb to /media/frank/autousb.

Any help is greatly appreciated.